# js extract property values by name

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
{
name: "user",
facebook: {
    followers: 2341
},
instagram: {
    followers: 5345
}
}
```

How can I get an array of all followers values without explicitely specifying the path (e.g. It could also be twitter instead of facebook)

```
[2341, 5345]
```

Comment: Is their a possibilty of any nesting, or is the structure you show limited to that depth?

Comment: @JAAulde yes, there may be nesting. Thanks for the hint

Comment: Your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to want to use a for .. in loop to loop over all the properties of the object, then check if they have a followers property, and finally add that property to a list. E.g.:

```js
let myObj = {
  name: "user",
  facebook: {
      followers: 2341
  },
  instagram: {
      followers: 5345
  }
}

let followers = [];

for (var prop in myObj) {
  if (myObj[prop].hasOwnProperty('followers') && typeof myObj[prop].followers === 'number'){
    followers.push(myObj[prop].followers);
  }
}
  
console.log(followers)
```

Comment: sry, I forgot to mention that the properties may also be nested deeper in the object

Comment: @Chris, how deep? Can you give a sample object?

Comment: If you need deeply nested 'followers', you need an entirely different approach. Check out @robert's answer

Answer (score 1):

This script searches for all occurrences of the keyword "followers" and adds it value to the array...

```js
var followers = {
  name: "user",
  facebook: {
    followers: 2341,
    test: {
      followers: 1,
    },
  },
  instagram: {
    followers: 5345
  }
};

var followerArray = [];

var getFollowers = function(obj) {
  for (var node in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[node] === 'object') {
      getFollowers(obj[node]);
    }
    
    if (node === 'followers') {
      followerArray.push(obj[node]);
    }
  }
}

getFollowers(followers);

console.log(followerArray);
```